# Custom XML Serialization applying only to properties

Tags: c#, xml, xmlserializer

Is possible using custom method only in fields? I can do this with JsonConver. I just need to create my custom class extended by JsonConverter and override the method JsonWriter, so in my properties I can mark with my custom class.

Example using Json:

```
public class CustomSerializer: JsonConverter
{
   public int Value {get; set;}

   public CustomSerializer(int value){               
      Value = value;
   }

   public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
   {
      // here my custom deserializer and i can use my prop Value
   }

   public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
   {
      // Here my custom serializer and i can use my prop Value           
   }
}
```

In my model using JsonConverter i can do this:

```
public class Person
{
    [JsonConverter(typeof(CustomSerializer))]
    public String Name{ get; set; }    
}
```

So when the object will be serialized or deserialized using JsonConvert, only the field decorated will receive a custom handling.

In my searches I found IXmlSerializer that we can extend, but it does't work to primitive values.